# dnd toolkit no deja controlar cliks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, drag-and-drop

Estoy desarrollando un todo-app con react y [zustand](https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/getting-started/introduction) para manejar el state y a la vez estoy usando [Dnd Kit](https://dndkit.com/) para añadir funcionalidad de reorganizar las tareas.

El problema es que la implementación de dnd kit requiere que agregue unas propiedades al div principal del componente ToDo (una tarea individual):

```
const Todo = ({ text, done, id }: ToDo) => {
    const { attributes, listeners, setNodeRef, transform, transition } =
        useSortable({ id });

    const style = {
        transform: CSS.Transform.toString(transform),
        transition,
    };

    const toggleTodo = useTodosStore((state) => state.toggleTodo);

    const removeTodo = useTodosStore((state) => state.removeTodo);

    const handleDone = () => {
        toggleTodo(id);
    };

    const handleRemoveTodo = () => {
        removeTodo(id);
    };

    return (
        <div
            className="todo-wrapper"
            {...attributes}
            {...listeners}
            ref={setNodeRef}
            style={style}
        >
            <div className="done-name">
                {/* Only show check mark when todo is done */}
                {done ? (
                    <img className="check" src="/icon-check.svg" alt="" />
                ) : (
                    ""
                )}
                <input
                    onChange={handleDone}
                    checked={done}
                    type="checkbox"
                    name="done"
                    id="done"
                />
                <span className={`todo-text ${done ? "done" : ""}`}>
                    {text}
                </span>
            </div>
            <img
                onClick={handleRemoveTodo}
                src="/icon-cross.svg"
                alt="cross icon"
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```

En concreto la prop  `{...listeners}`, hace que los eventos de click que tengo tanto en el input[type="check"] y el click en la imagen para eliminar una tarea no se disparen.

Coloqué un console.log(), para verificar que el evento no se está disparando, si quito la prop `{...listeners}` los eventos funcionan correctamente y zustand efectivamente cambia el estado de la tarea.
Tengo entendido que esa prop añade unos listeners relacionados con drag and drop,
y está bloqueando los eventos, la removí, pero no sirve la funcionalidad de Drag and Drop, como puedo solucionarlo para que los eventos de cambio de estado se disparen y a la vez tener la funcionalidad Drag and Drop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la respuesta:

Hay que darle una constraint para que el evento drag se active solo se active cuando se ha movido una distancia o un delay de tiempo.

En mi caso lo haré con una limitación de distancia, se hace creando un objeto sensors:

```
import { DndContext, PointerSensor, closestCenter, useSensor, useSensors } from "@dnd-kit/core";

const sensors = useSensors(
    useSensor(PointerSensor, {
        activationConstraint: {
            distance: 8,
        },
    })
);
```

Y después pasarlo como atributo al componente DndContext (usualmente envuelve la app):

```
        <DndContext
            collisionDetection={closestCenter}
            onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
            sensors={sensors}
        >
```

Haciendo esto los eventos de click funcionan correctamente.